# Não consigo entrar no "EOF"

Tags: c++, uri

Estou tentando resolver o seguinte problema do URI
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o problema está na hora de fazer o EOF acontecer, eu entendi mais ou menos como funciona mas ainda sim não consigo fazer meu programa "parar".

```
int main(){
string entrada;
Arv_bin * arv = new Arv_bin;
getline(cin, entrada);
do{
    entrada = remove_espacos(entrada);
    arv->raiz = cria_nodo(entrada, 0, entrada.length()-1);
    imprime_arv(arv);
    getline(cin, entrada);
    if(cin.eof()) cout << endl;
}while(!cin.eof());
return 0;}
```

Tem algo errado com a minha condição? O que eu deveria fazer?

Comment: Note que se der EOF na primeira leitura você irá tratar mesmo assim. Troque o `do { ...} while` por um `while(!cin.eof()) {...`. É desnecessário este `if(cin.eof()) cout << endl;` basta colocar `cout << endl;` após o loop.

Answer (score 0):

No URI (URI Online Judge), EOF (end-of-file) se refere ao final do arquivo que será usado no teste para verificar o código. Nesse caso, temos diferentes formas  para a leitura da entrada (istream/iostream) até o fim do arquivo (eof). Como:

```
while(getline(cin, entrada)){}
```

No C++ ocorre que o *cin* retornará falso quanto tiver um erro ou foi atingido o final do arquivo, e verdadeiro caso contrário. Enquanto não chegar no final do arquivo o *while* estará na condição de verdadeiro e executando. Quando chegar no final do arquivo, *cin* retornará falso e sua estrutura de repetição será terminado.

Estudos sobre *[streambuf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf), [istream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/)* e *[ios_base::iostate flags](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof)* esclareceram sobre o assunto.